# Error grouping multiple groups in one list

Tags: c#, console

I have some sets and the name of these sets will be random, it won't be sequential. The challenge I'm facing is to keep these sets on a list

But first I created a class that will have the following values ​​to store this information:

```
 public class Group
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public List<string> Sub { get; set; }
 }
```

Next I have the information below:

```
RandomName1:
- line1
- line2
- line3

RandomName4:
- line1
- line2
- line3

RandomName3:
- line1
- line2
- line3
```

I have already tried to do the following to group these items above into the Group class:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("groups.yml",Encoding.Default);
        List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
        Regex rgGroup = new Regex(@".*?\:");
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string line = lines[i];
            if (rgGroup.IsMatch(line))
            {
                groups.Add(new Group() { Name = line, Sub = new List<string>() });
            }
            else
            {
                 groups.LastOrDefault().Sub.Add(line);                    
            }
        }
```

The code is returning me this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not defined for an
>   instance of an object.' System.Linq.Enumerable.LastOrDefault 
>   (...) returned null.

. Looks like I made some inaccuracies in the code, why is this error showing up? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Q: What do you see when you step through the MSVS debugger?

Comment: returns me this error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not defined for an instance of an object.' System.Linq.Enumerable.LastOrDefault <TSource> (...) returned null.

Comment: No!  I meant to step through the debugger *to see which variable is "null"*!  I suspect probably "line"...  Another thing you can try is using temp variable. EXAMPLE: `Group tmpGroup = groups.LastOrDefault();`  "tmpGroup" might easily be null sometimes :)

Comment: Got it, is giving error in the else block

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
 groups.LastOrDefault()?.Sub?.Add(line);
```